# How to turn off validation based on a condition in c#

Tags: c#, validation

I have the following regex that validates an id number. I want to turn off validation based on the country

```
 public class validate{

            [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+", ErrorMessage = "Please enter ID number")]
            public string IdNumber { get; set; }
}
```

so when i come in this class i want to check the country as follows

```
  public class turnoffOn(command){
     if (command.country=10){
      //then keep the validation
idNumber=command.IdNumber
    }
    else {
    //turn off validation
   IdNumber=null;
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll either have to create your own `RegularExpressionAttribute`, which can inherit from the `RegularExpressionaAttribute` or implement the `IValidatableObject` interface (the simpler solution if you don't need this in multiple places).